# template argument deduction/substitution failed in multithreading

Tags: multithreading, templates

I'm running into this template deduction/substitution problem when passing a function through. Could someone help, I'd appreciate it very much:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <future>


template< class D > class Region
{

public:

  virtual bool                   setRegion( D& );

protected:


  int                            computeValue( int input, D& dataPack );
  template < class Fn > bool     setRegionValue( const int, D&, Fn&& );
  template < class Fn > bool     setAllValues( D&, Fn&& );

protected:

  std::vector< int >                  m_regionValues;
  std::vector< std::future< bool > >  m_futures;
};



template< class D > int Region< D >::computeValue( const int input,
                                                   D& dataPack )
{
  return input * dataPack.getData();
}


template< class D > 
template < class Fn > bool Region< D >::setRegionValue( const int input,
                                                        D& dataPack,
                                                        Fn&& function )
{
  int output = function( input, dataPack, output );
  m_regionValues.push_back( output * 2 );
  //check..
  return true;
}
  

template< class D > 
template< class Fn > bool Region< D >::setAllValues( D& dataPack,
                                                     Fn&& fn )
{
  for ( int indx = 0; indx < 10; ++indx )
  {
    int input = indx * 5;
    m_futures.push_back( std::async( std::launch::async,
                                     &Region::setRegionValue< std::remove_reference_t< Fn > >,
                                     this, input, std::ref( dataPack ),
                                     std::forward< Fn >( fn ) ) );
  }

  //check thread status..
  return true;
}


template< class D > bool Region< D >::setRegion( D& dataPack )
{
  auto func = std::bind( &Region::computeValue, this,
                         std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 );
  
  return setAllValues( dataPack, func );
}


struct Region1Data
{
  int        m_regionData;
  int        getData() const;
};


int Region1Data::getData() const
{
  return m_regionData;
}
  

class Region1: public Region< Region1Data >
{
public:

  bool                         setRegion( Region1Data& );
  void                         outputValue();
};


void Region1::outputValue()
{
  //..
}


bool Region1::setRegion( Region1Data& dataPack )
{
  if ( !Region::setRegion( dataPack ) )
  {
    return false;
  }

  outputValue();
  return true;
}


int main()
{
  Region1 thisRegion;
  Region1Data dataPack;
  dataPack.m_regionData = 10;
  
  thisRegion.setRegion( dataPack );
  return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors when compiling the code:

> example.cpp: In instantiation of 'bool Region::setAllValues(D&, Fn&&) [with Fn = std::_Bind::*)(int, Region1Data&)>(Region*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>)>&; D = Region1Data]':
>   example.cpp:72:39:   required from 'bool Region::setRegion(D&) [with D = Region1Data]'
>   example.cpp:106:17:   required from here
>   example.cpp:59:63: error: no matching function for call to 'async(std::launch, , Region*, int&, std::reference_wrapper, std::_Bind::*)(int, Region1Data&)>(Region*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>)>&)'
>                                         std::forward< Fn >( fn ) ) );
>                                                                  ^
>   example.cpp:59:63: note: candidates are:
>   In file included from example.cpp:3:0:
>   /opt/devl/optimize/gcc-4.9.3/include/c++/4.9.3/future:75:5: note: template std::future::type> std::async(std::launch, _Fn&&, _Args&& ...)
>        async(launch __policy, _Fn&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
>        ^
>   /opt/devl/optimize/gcc-4.9.3/include/c++/4.9.3/future:75:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   /opt/devl/optimize/gcc-4.9.3/include/c++/4.9.3/future: In substitution of 'template std::future::type> std::async(std::launch, _Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = bool (Region::*)(int, Region1Data&, std::_Bind::*)(int, Region1Data&)>(Region*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>)>&&); _Args = {Region*, int&, std::reference_wrapper, std::_Bind::*)(int, Region1Data&)>(Region*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>)>&}]':
>   example.cpp:59:63:   required from 'bool Region::setAllValues(D&, Fn&&) [with Fn = std::_Bind::*)(int, Region1Data&)>(Region*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>)>&; D = Region1Data]'
>   example.cpp:72:39:   required from 'bool Region::setRegion(D&) [with D = Region1Data]'
>   example.cpp:106:17:   required from here
>   /opt/devl/optimize/gcc-4.9.3/include/c++/4.9.3/future:75:5: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of::*(Region*, int&, std::reference_wrapper, std::_Bind::*)(int, Region1Data&)>(Region*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>)>&))(int, Region1Data&, std::_Bind::*)(int, Region1Data&)>(Region*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>)>&&)>'
>   example.cpp: In instantiation of 'bool Region::setAllValues(D&, Fn&&) [with Fn = std::_Bind::*)(int, Region1Data&)>(Region*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>)>&; D = Region1Data]':
>   example.cpp:72:39:   required from 'bool Region::setRegion(D&) [with D = Region1Data]'
>   example.cpp:106:17:   required from here
>   /opt/devl/optimize/gcc-4.9.3/include/c++/4.9.3/future:95:5: note: template std::future::type> std::async(_Fn&&, _Args&& ...)
>        async(_Fn&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
>        ^
>   /opt/devl/optimize/gcc-4.9.3/include/c++/4.9.3/future:95:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   /opt/devl/optimize/gcc-4.9.3/include/c++/4.9.3/future: In substitution of 'template std::future::type> std::async(_Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = std::launch; _Args = {bool (Region::*)(int, Region1Data&, std::_Bind::*)(int, Region1Data&)>(Region*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>)>&&), Region*, int&, std::reference_wrapper, std::_Bind::*)(int, Region1Data&)>(Region*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>)>&}]':
>   example.cpp:59:63:   required from 'bool Region::setAllValues(D&, Fn&&) [with Fn = std::_Bind::*)(int, Region1Data&)>(Region*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>)>&; D = Region1Data]'
>   example.cpp:72:39:   required from 'bool Region::setRegion(D&) [with D = Region1Data]'
>   example.cpp:106:17:   required from here
>   /opt/devl/optimize/gcc-4.9.3/include/c++/4.9.3/future:95:5: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of::*)(int, Region1Data&, std::_Bind::*)(int, Region1Data&)>(Region*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>)>&&), Region*, int&, std::reference_wrapper, std::_Bind::*)(int, Region1Data&)>(Region*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>)>&)>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setAllValues` is called with Lvalue:

```
template< class D > bool Region< D >::setRegion( D& dataPack ) {
  auto func = std::bind( &Region::computeValue, this,
                         std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 );

  return setAllValues( dataPack, func );         // func as named object is Lvalue
}
```

Due to forwarding reference rules `Fn` is deduced to be `Fn&` - as Lvalue reference.

```
template< class D > 
template< class Fn > bool Region< D >::setAllValues( D& dataPack,
                                                     Fn&& fn )          // Fn is Fn&
```

In below

```
&Region::setRegionValue< std::remove_reference_t< Fn > >,
                        ^^^ you put explicitly type in template argument list
```

referenceness of `Fn` is removed. Because you specify explicitly parameter of `setRegionValue` to be `Fn`, type of its third parameter is `Fn&&` - Rvalue ref. 
Forwarding Lvalue by `forward<Fn>(fn)` to Rvalue doesn't match, and that is why the code failed.

To handle `Fn` as Lvalue you could write:

```
template< class D > 
template< class Fn > bool Region< D >::setAllValues( D& dataPack,
                                                     Fn&& fn ) {             // Fn& &&fn
  for ( int indx = 0; indx < 10; ++indx )
  {
    int input = indx * 5;
    m_futures.push_back( std::async( std::launch::async,
                                     &Region::setRegionValue< Fn >,          // <- here is Fn&
                                     this, input, std::ref( dataPack ),
                                     std::ref( fn ) ) );                     // <-
  }
  return true;
}
```

in case of `&Region::setRegionValue< Fn >`, `setRegionValue` takes its third parameter as `Fn&`.
Because `async` takes all its parameters by value (as decayed) you have to use `std::ref`
to wrap Lvalue into `std::reference_wrapper`.

[Working version 1](https://godbolt.org/z/X57suB)

---

Above code doesn't handle case when passing Rvalue into `setAllValues`.

If you wrote:

```
return setAllValues( dataPack, std::bind( &Region::computeValue, this,
                         std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 ) );
```

definition of `setAllValues` should be:

```
template< class D > 
template< class Fn > bool Region< D >::setAllValues( D& dataPack,
                                                     Fn&& fn ) {
  for ( int indx = 0; indx < 10; ++indx )
  {
    int input = indx * 5;
    m_futures.push_back( std::async( std::launch::async,
                                     &Region::setRegionValue< Fn >,
                                     this, input, std::ref( dataPack ),
                                     std::forward<Fn>( fn ) ) );
  }
  return true;
}
```

in which `fn` as temporary is just forwarded.

[Working version 2](https://godbolt.org/z/ZkxE35)

---

It is hard to accommodate `std::ref` (which is required by `std::async`) with `std::forward` in one call, you could make two overloads:

```
template < class Fn > bool     setAllValues( D&, Fn&& );   // uses std::forward
template < class Fn > bool     setAllValues( D&, Fn& );    // uses std::ref
```

to handle both cases.

Comment: T'hanks so much @rafix07, that solves the problem! Much appreciate it!!!